# How to open image.png using a PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell

Setting the below `$usbDriveLetter` variable to automatically find the USB drive letter, and using that variable to open an image on the USB doesn't work. It literally prints "G:\image.png" in the cmd.

```
$usbDriveLetter = (gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''USB_NAME_HERE''').Name;
"$usbDriveLetter" + "image.png"
```

But if I don't use a var and make "G:\" static in the PowerShell script, the image opens just fine.

```
G:\image.png
```

So what am I doing wrong here? How do we dynamically open images using ps1 scripts?

Comment: If the suggested answer satisfies you, please consider mark it, as it will mark the question as answered.

Comment: You could add to the question title `...using a script and the powershell terminal`. This is how I found your question.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`Start-Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1) (or its `start` alias) command.

`start G:\image.png`

Or

`start $usbDriveLetter"image.png"`

It will open your image with the default application set to open png files (or ask you to choose one if no default image viewer is set).

Note from the comments, by [flolilolilo](https://superuser.com/users/703240/flolilolilo): Notice that just calling a variable will print its value. In your case, you actually want to use it as the `Start-Process` command parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the command a one-liner:

```
start ((gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''USB_NAME_HERE''').name + "image.png" )
```

Also, it appears you no longer need to use Start/Start-Process, just use the image name:
[image]